# App removed from Google play store because of disabled Google Account

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I found out that my Google account has been disabled but I was able to activate it about 24 hours after it had been disabled. About 12 hours later I got an email notification that my apps have been removed from Google Play because their records indicates that my Google Account may have been disabled. But since I had already activated my account I published a new update of the app as requested and was successfully published. Unfortunately it was removed again and received the same email notification that my apps were removed because my Google Account was disabled hence I have no access to my Google Play Developer Account. Though this was not the case because my Google Account was still active and still active. I updated the app again and released a new version that was on Friday. The update has not been published and is still under reviewed but I received an email notification (on that same friday) about my apps have been removed due to Google account being disabled. To today is on Monday but the update is still under review and I'm thinking of trying to release a new version before the previous release goes live on Google play because normally updates do take few hours about 2-4 hours but this has taken more than 48 hours now,

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I'm not sure what the question exactly is.  But in any case, questions about app store policies are off topic.

Comment: So is it wrong to release a new version before the previous release has been reviewed because somehow I feel like there was a bug on their side that's why they were indicating that my Google Account was is disabled while it's active?

Comment: It's not wrong but the new release will be reviewed and if approved it shall be published.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.